# How to express alternating $-1,0,1$ in a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am dealing with a series that has a term: $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$

How would I express this without the sine function?

I know it alternates $1, 0, -1, 0, 1, \dots$

Can I express this as $-1$ raised to some power?

Comment: Not if you only want something of the form $(-1)^k$ (since you can't get 0).

Answer (score 4):

I believe (with $n$ starting at 0)
$$ \frac{i^n (1 + (-1)^n)}{2} $$
does the trick.  If you want the index to begin at $1$ then simply replace $n$ with $n-1$ above.

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right)$ does not converge. If you're dealing with something like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}\right) f(n)$ with $f$ some function, then you could replace the series by $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}f(2n-1)$, since all other terms in the series are $0$ anyway.

Comment: The series is Cesaro summable, though, so it is not all bad.